# Порядок внутри оператора IN

Tags: sql, mysql

У меня простой вопрос, влияет ли на скорость порядок ID внутри оператора IN?
Например,

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (221258, 121257, 977256, 2255, 52223, 50, 222222)`

будет ли выполняться дольше, чем

`SELECT * FROM test WHERE id IN (50, 2255, 52223, 121257, 221258, 222222, 977256)`
?

Синтетические тесты не показали существенной разницы, но как на самом деле?

Comment: Мне кажется, что на объёмах задаваемых прямыми числами в запросе, основное время будет уходить на парсинг запроса. А если указывать под запроса, то с нужными индексами, он сам разберётся, какой нужен порядок. С точки зрения тупого алгоритма - по идее, должен влиять, исходя из того, что он сравнивает перебором.

Comment: @Чад, с одной стороны понимаю, что сортировка должна помочь, ведь бегать по порядку удобнее, чем туда-сюда. Но с другой - вдруг SQL сам оптимизирует эти моменты, а я лишний раз буду PHP напрягать

Comment: @Чад, а как MySQL узнает о том, что у вас данные отсортированы? Только если он сам их отсортирует, либо вы ему об этом сообщите. Я не знаю ни одной константы, которая говорила бы об этом. Т.е. если MySQL сам не сортирует, то ему без разницы в каком порядке переданы данные. А если сортирует - то ему также без разницы порядок данных. Т.е. как ни крути - порядок не важен.

Comment: @BOPOH, а я что написал? :-)

Comment: @Чад,

>> С точки зрения тупого алгоритма - по идее должен влиять, исходя из того что он сравнивает перебором.

Я про это.

Хотя сейчас сижу и думаю - а вдруг и правда выгода есть? Вместо `M * log N` (где M - число в списке, а N - число в индексе) будет в худшем случае где-то `log M + 2 log N`? Или накладные расходы в среднем сведут все на нет?

Comment: @BOPOH, ну, я думаю, парсинг запроса съест больше всего, если там будет, например, 10000 id ков

Comment: А если наоборот? Если он сам сортирует, тогда при уже отсортированном списке сортировка может отрабатывать по худшему случаю алго)

Comment: Вообщем надо тех доки майскеля курить, если они такие предоставляют :-)

Comment: Для начала просто посмотрите план исполнения запроса (EXPLAIN SELECT ...)

Answer (score 1):

Список значений в предикате IN лучше перечислять от более часто используемых к менее.
Тогда если сравниваемое значение присутствует в списке, оно будет отобрано быстрей. Если значение отсутствует в списке, то все равно будет просмотрен весь список.

"Умный" оптимизатор на основании статистики (распределения значений) мог бы менять порядок следования значений, но я не слышал о таком. Да еще и накладные расходы на это нужно оценить.

UPD. Сделал простой тест. Поскольку в основном работаю с SQL Server, то на нём.

Генерация данных:

```
create table Tin (id int)
declare @N int=1000000
declare @i int =1
set nocount on;
while @i<100
begin
insert into Tin values(@i)
set @i=@i+1
end
while @i<=1000000
begin
insert into Tin values(999)
set @i=@i+1
end
```

Запросы:

```
select * from tin where 
ID in(100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,999)
go
select * from tin where 
ID in(999,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109)
```

Результаты (второй запрос показывает стабильно лучшие результаты по elapsed time):

```
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(999901 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1248 ms,  elapsed time = 17998 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(999901 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1264 ms,  elapsed time = 15905 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 57 ms.
```

UPD2
Должен отказаться от своего предположения, по крайней мере, для SQL Server.
В плане указан отсортированный список значений в IN. Вероятно, сервер выполняет сортировку значений перед сравнением.
Так что при большом числе прогонов, результаты должны быть практически одинаковыми.

Comment: А смысл этого "быстрей", если все равно придется искать все значения в списке? От того, что какое-то значение будет найдено быстрее, весь список быстрее перебран все равно не будет.

С отсортированным списком может быть чуть быстрее, т.к. если мы проверили первое значение и нашли его, то второе значение из списка надо будет искать не с начала дерева индексов, а уже ниже найденного. Но это копейки, скорее всего.

Comment: Такой пример. Вы ищете пользователей по городу проживания. И у вас 90% из Москвы. А список такой:

(Нью-Йорк, Лондон, еще тысячапятьсот городов, Москва)

или такой

(Москва, Нью-Йорк, Лондон, еще тысячапятьсот городов)

Можете протестить на большой табличке.

Comment: @msi, пруфы можно по "все равно будет просмотрен весь список"?  
по индексированному полю будет поиск по ключу, а не full scan. учитывая id из вопроса так вообще утверждение странное.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, зачем просматривать весь список, если совпадение получено на первом элементе?

Comment: Хз, как в mysql, но в Oracle `IN (1, 2, 3)` раскладывается на `1 OR 2 OR 3`. От порядка ничего не зависит.

Comment: Совпадение с чем? Вы описали full scan. На самом деле берется список и для каждого элемента списка берется запись по индексу. Вас же не удивит, надеюсь,  что `select * from tab2kkkk_rows where id=45345345` выполнится ровно за 0.00 секунд? Так и с in будет.  

Что касается сортированности списка, все верно сказал @BOPOH, если sql сортирует список, значит пофиг какой список будет передан сортированный или нет. И @Чад тоже верно сказал, сортировка списка сравнима с потерями на парсинг запроса.

ЗЫ был уже вопрос про `in`. Там тоже хватало мифов, но тестить никто не хотел и все остались при своих

Comment: Ну, сортировка нескольких тысяч чисел потребует явно меньше 1 миллисекунды. 

На самом деле (в случае таблицы разумного размера) все время выполнения будет определяться скоростью ее чтения (причем первого, потом данные окажутся уже в файловом кэше) с диска.

Comment: Результаты теста привел в ответе.

Comment: @msi, Вы пишете "Результаты (второй запрос показывает стабильно лучшие результаты):"


а если поменять местами запросы в тесте?

Comment: Поменял:

SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1294 ms,  elapsed time = 16393 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

(999901 row(s) affected)

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 1186 ms,  elapsed time = 17012 ms.
SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.

Хотя, соглашусь, что разница незначительная.

Comment: Что же, похоже (если @msi представил *средние* значения, а не единичный случай) и в самом деле при такой организации (в таблице нет индекса и явно маленький список в IN) используется последовательный просмотр списка.

Comment: @avp, "в таблице нет индекса и явно маленький список в IN" - это ключевой момент, тест пустой. 999901 row(s) affected - facepalm.

Answer (score 0):

Провёл с десяток разных тестов, с учётом погрешностей результаты были практически одинаковы. Лучшее время показывал то сортированный, то нет.

Пробовал запрашивать по 1000 раз запросы с одинаковыми сортированными значениями IN и не сортированными. Пробовал тоже самое, но добавлял рандомные ID в IN. База содержала >1млн записей, список внутри IN был ~20 ID.

Преимущества сортировки во время тестов я не заметил.

Для себя сделал вывод, что можно не париться над сортировкой.